# Firestore security rule for adding/removing values from a nested object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to figure out the security rules for someone adding/removing votes in a Firestore database. The document is setup like this

```
{
  meetingTitle: "Big Team Meeting",
  possibleMeetingTimes: {
    1548694800000: {
      user-id-1: "The best time for me.",
      user-id-2: "I'm free at this time."
    },
    1548694900000: {
      user-id-3: "I have to pick up my kids at the other time."
    }
  }
}
```

I want a user to be able to suggest a new date, add a vote to a date, and remove their vote from a date. They should not be able to remove/edit a date not associated with their `request.auth.uid`, nor should they be able to add a vote not associated with their `request.auth.uid`.

I'm not tied to this data setup if there is a better way to structure this data that would make my security requests easier to setup. I'm fairly new to Firestore security rules, so advice is welcome.

Comment: I think you'll have a much easier time with this if you make each date its own document, perhaps in a subcollection.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I was hoping that wouldn't be the case for easier querying. But if it makes the security rules much easier to do, I'll use your suggested approach. Thank you!